# Cannot insert to database using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have button and grid view in my app and whenever I click this button I want add new record to database and display updated table in grid view. But for some reason I cannot add but when I click this button again its says `'System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException'`. So it seems that it is added for my grid view is still the same and there is no chagnes in database.

This is my onclick method:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            database = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = database.Orders;
            Order order = new Order();
            order.Id = 32;
            order.units = 555;
            database.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);
            database.SubmitChanges();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = database.Orders;
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked database that record inserted?
If the record is added, the problem is for dataGridVeiw that is not updated, call `dataGridView1.Refresh()` after setting DataSource

Answer (score 0):

If your table Order in the database got the primary Key on ID, you can't add another Order with the same ID.
Then change your order.ID !

EDIT :
let `order.id` to `null`and add auto-increment to your primary-key
Maybe the DB won't let you add the Order because he got a value on the Id

Comment: yes it has primary key thats why I get duplicate id but first object is not added. It says that cannot add duplicate but that object wasnt added.